# Por que a atribuição múltipla de variáveis cria uma lista quando utilizada com o operador asterisco?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, python-internals

Supondo que há uma tupla com três valores, `('a', 1, 'b')`, e deseja-se atribuir o primeiro valor em uma variável e manter o restante em outra. Para isso é possível fazer:

```
a, *b = ('a', 1, 'b')
```

Assim, `a` possuirá o valor `'a'` enquanto `b` possuirá o valor `[1, 'b']`.

Por que o valor definido em `b` é uma lista?

Não consigo ver vantagens em criar uma estrutura mutável, como a lista, a partir de um valor fixo, como também não vejo motivos em se utilizar uma estrutura que semanticamente deveria ser homogênea para alocar dados possivelmente heterogêneos.

Tanto que quando utilizado como argumento de uma função o objeto criado é uma tupla:

```
def foo(a, *b):
    print(a, b)

foo('a', 1, 'b')  # a (1, 'b')
```

Não faria mais sentido `b` também ser uma tupla em `a, *b = ('a', 1, 'b')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estava lendo o livro que havia citado nos comentários novamente, e acabei me precipitando com a resposta. Dando uma pesquisada a fundo acabei achando a discussão:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007312.html

De acordo com *Greg* no link da discussão sobre a pep3132:

*não é possível saber de forma direta o tamanho de um iterador. O único jeito de retornar uma tupla, seria primeiro criando uma lista, para então criar uma tupla.*

Ou seja, necessitaria um passo a mais para o tratamento dos dados. Por isso é retornado uma lista.

Comment: Mas a pergunta é justamente o porquê que o "unpack" cria uma lista. Também não entendi a relação da `namedtuple` com a pergunta.

Comment: Porque  a tupla em si é imutável. É como disse " se você faz unpacking, é porque você irá manipular os dados a partir das variáveis que utilizou para o unpacking.". O namedtuple é para não haver necessidade de fazer o unpack e conseguir utilizar a tupla como se fosse uma variável, não havendo necessidade de fazer o unpacking. Vou tentar ser mais conciso na resposta.

Comment: **1)** _"por padrão *args monta uma lista"_: o AP prova que quando o _unpacking_ é feito nos argumentos de uma função, o retorno é uma tupla e não uma lista. Sua afirmação não faz sentido. **2)** _"Unpack serve para instanciar um valor imutável em uma variável mutável"_: li a [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) e não achei essa afirmação. **3)** _"Se você quiser trabalhar com tuplas nomeadas, o recomendado é utilizar namedtuple"_: Não entendi a relação com a pergunta e `namedtuples` é a única implementação nativa de Tuplas Nomeadas, então me parece óbvia a afirmação

Comment: "This PEP proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a **list** of all items not assigned to a "regular" name."
Por isso recomendei *namedtuple* para não haver necessidade de salvar na memória uma tupla que já possa ter sido criada. E não precisa "achar" essa afirmação, é simples. Tuplas são imutáveis, e só tem dois sentidos de fazer unpacking, manipular dados, ou nomea-los. Por isso citei namedtuples. O conhecimento que estou me basendo é num livro escrito por *Luciano Ramalho*, **Fluent Python**.

Comment: Tenho o Fluent Python, vou dar uma olhada quando chegar em casa. E mesmo com o que você mencionou, sua afirmação _"Unpack serve para instanciar um valor imutável em uma variável mutável"_ segue não fazendo sentido. E talvez não tenha ficado claro, mas o AP gostaria de entender qual o motivo de decidirem por listas ao invés de tuplas e porque este comportamento não é o mesmo quando desempacotamos argumentos posicionais. E apenas uma discussão para entender o porquê essa decisão foi tomada, sabemos que é uma lista, mas deveria ser uma lista?

Comment: Hmm, então, mas aí que está. Qual seria o sentido em *desempacotar* uma tupla para outra tupla? É isso o que estou colocando em pauta. Se fosse apenas para dar nome aos valores da tupla, não seria mais interessante utilizar namedtuple para este caso? Qual seria o sentido de criar uma tupla a partir de outra tupla(?)

Comment: `a, *b, c = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` ficaria `1, (2, 3, 4), 5`.. Faria tanto sentido quanto uma lista pois você está quebrando uma sequencia em pedaços, com a diferença é que semanticamente uma tupla faria mais sentido pois é uma representação fixa do "pedaço" da sequência. A discussão é legal, o difícil é achar uma resposta do porquê essa decisão foi tomada deste jeito, pois na PEP 3132 é especificado que é uma lista, mas não explica porque tem que ser uma lista. PS: Qual capítulo do Python Fluente você se referiu? Não vou conseguir ler todo ele agora até de tarde hahahah

Comment: Qualquer coisa vamos pro chat do SOPt a tarde... aqui tá comprido demais já

Comment: página 27 começa Tuple Unpacking. Tenho que ir trabalhar, mas vou dar uma ida lá no chat

Comment: (não vi como estava o texto anterior da resposta - mas a resposta atual parece satisfatória para mim)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei o quanto isso resonde a sua pergunta, mas essa implementação (lista no lugar de tupla) permite utilizar a sintaxe do * mesmo em casos onde o tamanho da sequência é desconhecida, como em geradores:

```
>>> gen = (x**2 for x in range(5))
>>> len(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
>>> first, *rest = gen
>>> first
0
>>> rest
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Aparentemente **uma única implementação é utilizada para a sintaxe do ***, fazendo com que funcione da mesma forma para qualquer iterável - juntando todos os elementos sobressalentes em uma lista - independente do tipo de iterável (lista, tupla, gerador ou até mesmo strings):

```
>>> first, *rest = 'mystring'
>>> first
'm'
>>> rest
['y', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Imagino que seria possível implementar a sintaxe do * de forma a retornar os elementos no mesmo tipo de dado inicial (tupla para tupla, string para string...), mas em alguns casos (como no do gerador) isso não daria certo. E aí estaríamos nos perguntando se seria melhor passar estes valores para lista ou tupla... :-)